# How to copy a script file in to all subdirectories?

Tags: bash, shell, python-2.7

1. I have a python script file .

problem 
 I want to copy this file in to all the subdirectories?

Need a shell script which does this task ?

Please help me on this .Thanks in Advance

Comment: Sounds like a maintenance nightmare! Can't you put the script in `/usr/local/scripts` or somewhere and execute it from there rather than have 37,000 different copies and versions all over the place? And if you absolutely *have to* run it from each directory, couldn't you symbolic link to a single script elsewhere so you only have a single place to maintain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `find` command with the `-type d` option to find all the subdirectories recursively in your main directory, and the `-exec` option to run a `cp` operation

```
find <mydirectory> -type d -exec cp myfile.py {} \;
```

I suggest you try

```
find <mydirectory> -type d -exec echo {} \;
```

first to identify the directories that will be affected.

More information:  `man find`

Comment: Just wanted to know what is the use of adding this at the end {} \;

Comment: `{}` is the name of the file you just found.  `\;` marks the end of the command.  Please read `man find`.  It's all in there.